# What are these Nvidia flatpak packages?

Tags: nvidia, flatpak

On Linux Mint (updated and upgraded regularly) current version 21.1 Vera, apart from regular system and "*normally*" installed applications, I also periodically check for graphics card driver updates on the [Nvidia main driver page](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us), and if there is an update for Linux, I check with `apt-cache policy ...` for it. For me, the recent version is 525, so I assume(-d) I could remove all old `org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.nvidia-[version]` packages like this, and I did it, apart from the 525 version, logically:

```
$ flatpak uninstall --delete-data org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.nvidia-435-21


        ID                                                  Branch           Op
 1. [-] org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.nvidia-435-21           1.4              r

Uninstall complete.
Delete data for org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.nvidia-435-21? [y/n]: y
```

---

```
$ flatpak list
Name                                                   Application ID                                           Version               Branch                 Origin                         Installation
Caprine                                                com.sindresorhus.Caprine                                 2.57.0                stable                 flathub                        system
HandBrake                                              fr.handbrake.ghb                                         1.5.1                 stable                 flathub                        system
IntelMediaSDK plugin for HandBrake                     fr.handbrake.ghb.Plugin.IntelMediaSDK                                          1                      intelmediasdk-origin           system
Freedesktop Platform                                   org.freedesktop.Platform                                 21.08.17.1            21.08                  flathub                        system
default                                                org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.default                                            1.6                    gnome                          system
Mesa                                                   org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.default                      21.3.9                21.08                  flathub                        system
Mesa                                                   org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.default                      22.3.2                22.08                  flathub                        system
Mesa (Extra)                                           org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.default                      22.3.2                22.08-extra            flathub                        system
nvidia-435-21                                          org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.nvidia-435-21                                      1.4                    flathub                        system
nvidia-440-100                                         org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.nvidia-440-100                                     1.4                    flathub                        system
nvidia-440-59                                          org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.nvidia-440-59                                      1.4                    flathub                        system
nvidia-450-66                                          org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.nvidia-450-66                                      1.4                    flathub                        system
nvidia-450-80-02                                       org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.nvidia-450-80-02                                   1.4                    flathub                        system
nvidia-455-38                                          org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.nvidia-455-38                                      1.4                    flathub                        system
nvidia-455-45-01                                       org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.nvidia-455-45-01                                   1.4                    flathub                        system
nvidia-460-32-03                                       org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.nvidia-460-32-03                                   1.4                    flathub                        system
nvidia-460-39                                          org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.nvidia-460-39                                      1.4                    flathub                        system
nvidia-460-56                                          org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.nvidia-460-56                                      1.4                    flathub                        system
nvidia-460-73-01                                       org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.nvidia-460-73-01                                   1.4                    flathub                        system
nvidia-460-80                                          org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.nvidia-460-80                                      1.4                    flathub                        system
nvidia-465-27                                          org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.nvidia-465-27                                      1.4                    flathub                        system
nvidia-470-103-01                                      org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.nvidia-470-103-01                                  1.4                    flathub                        system
nvidia-470-57-02                                       org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.nvidia-470-57-02                                   1.4                    flathub                        system
nvidia-470-63-01                                       org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.nvidia-470-63-01                                   1.4                    flathub                        system
nvidia-470-74                                          org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.nvidia-470-74                                      1.4                    flathub                        system
nvidia-470-86                                          org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.nvidia-470-86                                      1.4                    flathub                        system
nvidia-495-44                                          org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.nvidia-495-44                                      1.4                    flathub                        system
nvidia-495-46                                          org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.nvidia-495-46                                      1.4                    flathub                        system
nvidia-510-47-03                                       org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.nvidia-510-47-03                                   1.4                    flathub                        system
nvidia-510-54                                          org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.nvidia-510-54                                      1.4                    flathub                        system
nvidia-510-60-02                                       org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.nvidia-510-60-02                                   1.4                    flathub                        system
nvidia-510-73-05                                       org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.nvidia-510-73-05                                   1.4                    flathub                        system
nvidia-515-48-07                                       org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.nvidia-515-48-07                                   1.4                    flathub                        system
nvidia-515-65-01                                       org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.nvidia-515-65-01                                   1.4                    flathub                        system
nvidia-515-76                                          org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.nvidia-515-76                                      1.4                    flathub                        system
nvidia-525-60-11                                       org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.nvidia-525-60-11                                   1.4                    flathub                        system
Intel                                                  org.freedesktop.Platform.VAAPI.Intel                                           21.08                  flathub                        system
Intel                                                  org.freedesktop.Platform.VAAPI.Intel                                           22.08                  flathub                        system
openh264                                               org.freedesktop.Platform.openh264                        2.1.0                 2.0                    flathub                        system
openh264                                               org.freedesktop.Platform.openh264                        2.1.0                 2.2.0                  flathub                        system
GNOME Application Platform version 43                  org.gnome.Platform                                                             43                     flathub                        system
GNOME Software Development Kit version 3.28            org.gnome.Sdk                                                                  3.28                   gnome                          system
Mint-Y Gtk Theme                                       org.gtk.Gtk3theme.Mint-Y                                                       3.22                   flathub                        system
Mint-Y-Aqua Gtk Theme                                  org.gtk.Gtk3theme.Mint-Y-Aqua                                                  3.22                   flathub                        system
Mint-Y-Dark-Purple Gtk Theme                           org.gtk.Gtk3theme.Mint-Y-Dark-Purple                                           3.22                   flathub                        system
```

---

- **What are these Nvidia flatpak packages?**
- **How do these packages come to my OS without my permission?**

---

I may have found a clue:

Menu -> Software -> Updates -> 3-dashed button on top right -> Update Preferences:

[image]

PS: I also wonder, why don't I have only the latest version installed?

Comment: AFAIK, Flatpaks pull in all required dependencies by themselves. This means that if a package is compiled using, say, GNOME 3.39, it pulls that in so that everything works as intended; if it didn't something could be broken, given that the package does not support GNOME 43. Don't know if this makes sense...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What are these Nvidia flatpak packages?

These packages are extensions for flatpak runtimes containing Nvidia drivers.

In general, you shouldn't have so many of them. (related issue: https://github.com/flatpak/flatpak/issues/5261 )

For now you can remove them manually with command: `flatpak remove --unused`.

> How do these packages come to my OS without my permission?

They are just dependencies, which are downloaded automatically when other flatpak apps are updated.